Vanishing of all higher direct images for a non-flat morphism
Let $f: X \to Y$ be a proper morphism of algebraic varieties which is not flat. Then for a line bundle $L$ on $X$, is the vanishing of all higher direct images ($R^i f_* L = 0$ for all $i \geq 0$) equivalent to the vanishing of all $H^i(f^{-1}(s), L|_{f^{-1}(s)})$ for all $i \geq 0$ and all points  $s \in Y$?

Do you want the morphism to be proper?  That already fails for open immersions.

@JasonStarr Yes, the morphism is proper, sorry, I fixed this in the question
